# How to fix CAMLJS undefined error?

Tags: caml

I am running a simple CamlJs, it works from Chrome Console and from the Chrome Extension. However when I try from a Content Editor Webpart (Sharepoint Online / O365) it gives me an error.

```
<script src="/sites/intranet/Style%20Library/CI/scripts/document_library/camljs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">       
 var str = new CamlBuilder()
            .Where()
            .LookupMultiField("Tag")
            .IncludesSuchItemThat()
            .ValueAsText()
            .In(['a', 'b', 'authorization form'])
            .ToString();
console.log(str);
</script>
```

This is the error:

```
camljs.js:948 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at Builder.Finalize (camljs.js:948)
    at QueryToken.ToString (camljs.js:304)
    at doclib.aspx:1123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put your code inside `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` block.
`camljs` uses some functions which are not availiable on document load.

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
var str = new CamlBuilder()
            .Where()
            .LookupMultiField("Tag")
            .IncludesSuchItemThat()
            .ValueAsText()
            .In(['a', 'b', 'authorization form'])
            .ToString();
console.log(str);  
}, 'sp.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that usually has to do with IE versions that don't render later jquery functions: try to load https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Comment: the bug was in chrome, I didn't even try in IE.